# Display custom message when asking for facebook permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

Is there any way to display a custom message when asking for permissions with facebook js sdk? For example if I ask for email permissions, I would like to add a message "Your email is needed in order to send your key to your files". Or something like that. Is it possible? What I mean is, of course doing it within the facebook auth dialog, not showing an alert or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

The OAuth2 Dialog is coming from FB. That's the way it works: You MUST not change that (or even add things!)

But: consider the scope variable in the request, this should give the user a hint what access rights you're requesting already.

Comment: Yeah, well, I thought it would look nicer. I will just make a little bit of documentation. The idea was that when I need to explain the user why certain permissions are needed. My app really needs A LOT of permissions- so I need to explain the user why, and what feature won't be available if the permissions are not granted